# Unique first column in multi-column index

Tags: mysql, indexing, constraints

I have multi-column index for 2 columns. Can I make first column unique without making separate index for that?

If I understand correctly mysql can use only first column in this index for lookups, so can it use it to detect uniqueness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked.

> I have multi-column index for 2 columns. Can I make first column unique without making separate index for that?

The answer is no. You need a separate unique index on the first column to enforce a uniqueness constraint.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "No". Because it doesn't make much sense.

Indeed, MySQL is able to use a multiple-column index for operations that use only the leftmost "n" columns from the index definition.

Let's say you have an index on columns `(col1, col2)`. MySQL can use it to find records matching conditions on both `col1` and `col2`, `GROUP BY col1, col2` or `ORDER BY col1, col2`. It is important to notice that `col1` and `col2` needs to used in this order in the `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` clause. Their order doesn't matter on `WHERE` or `ON` clauses as long as both are used.

MySQL can also use the same index for `WHERE` or `ON` conditions and `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` clauses that contain only `col1`. It cannot, however, use the index if `col2` appears without `col1`.

#### What happens when you have an index on columns `(col1, col2)` and all the rows have distinct values in column `col1`?

Let's assume we have a table that have distinct values in column `col1` and it has an index on columns `(col1, col2)`. When MySQL needs to find the rows that match `WHERE col1 = val1 AND col2 = val2`, by consulting the index it can find the row that have `col1 = val1`. It doesn't need to use the index to refine the list of candidate rows because there is no list: there is at most one row having `col1 = val1`.

Sure, most of the times MySQL **will** use the index to check if `col2 = val2` but having `col2` in this index doesn't bring more useful information to the index. The storage space it takes and the processing power it uses on table data updates are too big for the tiny contribution it adds to rows searching.

The whole purpose of having indexes on multiple columns is to help searching by shrinking the list of matching rows for a given set of values when the columns included in a multiple-column index cannot be used individually because they don't contain enough distinct values.

Technically speaking, there is no way to tell MySQL you want to have a multiple-column index on `(col1, col2)` that must have unique values on `col1`. Create an [`UNIQUE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) on `col1` instead. Then think about the data you have in the table and the queries you run against it and decide if another index on `col2` only isn't better than the multiple-column index on `(col1, col2)`.

In order to decide you can create the new indexes (`UNIQUE` on `col1`, `INDEX` on `col2`), put `EXPLAIN` in front of the most frequent queries you run on the table and check what index will pick MySQL up for use.

You need to have enough data (thousands of rows, at least, more is better) in the table to get accurate results.

Comment: I'm using it like this `where col1>val1 and col1<val2 and col2=val3` and val2 - val1 is about 10000000. So such index is useful in my case.